# Remove text from one field and output the result into another field.

Tags: infopath

We currently have emails that go out to people when an Project has been assigned to them.

However we want to make it so that when the Info Path Form is changed, it only sends out an email to the people who have not been emailed before.

We have tried, Translate to remove the text.

So for example:

It will be:

`Persons to be Emailed: Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk`

```
Persons Email List: Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk

Persons Emailed - Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk
```

Form is updated, and we add paul.bloggs@email.co.uk

Updated fields as below (how it should be):

```
Persons to be Emailed: Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk
Persons Email List: Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk | paul.bloggs@email.co.uk
Persons Emailed - Joe.Bloggs@email.co.uk
```

How do you remove the emails in Person Emailed from the Email List and then return the value in Persons to be emailed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `concat()` to append the new users email onto the email list. Ex:
`concat(PersonsEmailListField, " | ", EmailToAddField)`

You can concat as many things as you want, just keep adding parameters. You might also want to do some cleanup/integrity validation (check if there was data in the email to add field before appending, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you wanted to have the new email entry in the "Person to be Emailed".

Try this, create a rule in "Email List" field with no condition and with the following formula:

```
translate(substring-after(. , PersonsEmailed), " |","")
```

First part of the formula is `substring-after (., PersonsEmailed)` . In this formula, we are getting the new email entry  after the PersonsEmailed value.

The second part is translating the result. The raw result that we will be getting from the first formula ha spaces and it includes the "|" character. That is why we are translating any spaces and the character to no space.

Now after sending the email to the new email entry, you can use `concat()` to add the new email entry and the Emailed values and enter it in the PersonsEmailed field.